# Migrating Ubuntu Music Library to an External Hard Drive?

Tags: migration, media-library

I have a very small internal hard drive, and I want to migrate my music library to an external hard drive. How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is rather easy, if you are using a music player that keeps a database, such as Banshee or Clementine.

All you need to do, is cut and paste your music to a folder on the external hard drive, then import it to your music player. Just make sure that your music player's preferences are set to **not** import files to your `~/Music` folder.

Comment: Thanks! While we're on the topic, is there a specific music/media player/library you recommend?

Comment: @JShoe for the task, the two I mentioned are great :)